# Acccess my Wallet

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, wallets

I generated an account using geth on my PC. I was never fully synced with the blockchain. Can I access my wallet from another client? How would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the account was generated using geth. It's stored in a .json file under the keystore directory. The .json file contain the password encrypted private key. You can take the .json file and move it to a new client freely (into a new keystore directory in the new computer) or to use on online wallets.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand you to use Metamask https://metamask.io/
It is easy to use and configurable.

By default, it will connect you through some nodes.
But you can also specify which node to connect to.

Comment: So, I can import there my key that I have locally on my HD? or should i create a new account?